# SwiftUI: animate movement of a view from one stack to another?

Tags: ios, swiftui

## Background

Using SwiftUI, I'm working on the implementation of a Solitaire-like card game which includes stacking of playing cards and the ability to move cards from one stack to another, for example:

[image: Card movement]

In the example here, when I tap the "Move Card" button, the ♠️9 moves from column 1 to column 2, to sit on top of the ❤️10, and the animation is that the ♠️9 fades out from the first column, while a new ♠️9 simultaneously fades in on the second column.

**What I want** is for the ♠️9 view itself to animate *directly from its original position to its final position* on top of the ❤️10.

(In my actual app, there are other positions the cards can be in as well, but the implementations are similar to `ColumnView`.)

## Code

I have a data model consisting of a `Column` class which contains an array of `Card` objects, and corresponding `ColumnView` and `CardView` structures:

```
public class Column: Identifiable, ObservableObject {
    public let id: Int
    @Published var stack = [Card]()

    public init(id: Int, cards: [Card]? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.stack = cards ?? []
    }

    public func push(_ card: Card) {
        stack.append(card)
    }

    public func pop() -> Card {
        guard !stack.isEmpty else { fatalError() }
        return stack.removeLast()
    }

    public func orderIndex(for card: Card) -> Int {
        return stack.firstIndex(of: card) ?? -1
    }
}

public struct Card: Equatable, Identifiable {
    public let suit: Suit
    public let rank: Rank

    public var id: String { return displayTitle }

    public init(suit: Suit, rank: Rank) {
        self.suit = suit
        self.rank = rank
    }

    public var displayTitle: String {
        return "\(suit.displayTitle)\(rank.displayTitle)"
    }
}
```

```
public struct ColumnView: View {
    @ObservedObject var column: Column

    public init(column: Column) {
        self.column = column
    }

    public var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(column.stack) { card in
                CardView(card: card)
                    .offset(x: 0, y: 35*CGFloat(self.column.orderIndex(for: card)))
                    .frame(width: 125, height: 187)
            }
        }
    }
}


public struct CardView: View {
    let card: Card

    public init(card: Card) {
        self.card = card
    }

    public var body: some View {
        // Implementation that draws the card
    }
}
```

And finally a `Board` object which wraps the `Column` objects, and a corresponding `BoardView` to display (the main screen in this example):

```
struct Board {
    let column1: Column
    let column2: Column

    init() {
        // Convenience method for Card.ten.ofDiamonds, etc not shown.
        column1 = Column(id: 0, cards: [
            Card.ten.ofDiamonds,
            Card.nine.ofSpades
        ])

        column2 = Column(id: 1, cards: [
            Card.king.ofSpades,
            Card.queen.ofDiamonds,
            Card.jack.ofClubs,
            Card.ten.ofHearts
        ])
    }

    func moveCard() {
        let card = column1.pop()
        column2.push(card)
    }
}

struct BoardView: View {
    let board = Board()

    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)

            HStack(spacing: 20) {
                ColumnView(column: board.column1)
                ColumnView(column: board.column2)
            }

            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.board.moveCard()
                }
            }) {
                Text("Move Card")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .offset(x: 0, y: 300)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

## Question

It *makes sense* why the fade-out/fade-in happens - from the first `ColumnView`'s perspective, `column1` lost a card (card was removed from the `column1` array), so it transitions out with a fade-out; and from the second `ColumnView`'s perspective, `column2` gained a card (card was added to the `column2` array), so it transitions in with a fade-in.

The question is, is there a way to achieve what I want without having to completely re-architect the data model and view hierarchy I have set up, with `Card`s inside of `Column`s and `CardView`s inside of `ColumnView`s? It's really helpful to have that data model the way it is, and it's helpful to have the direct mapping of the data model to the view hierarchy.

I can imagine some sort of alternate view hierarchy where there are just 52 `CardView`s with some sort of modifiers for the positions based on what column or location they're in, but that feels very hacky. I thought about maybe some sort of custom `transition`, but transitions are for views being inserted or deleted. Is there a way to tell SwiftUI that the `Card` structure isn't being removed and re-added, but rather *moved*, and therefore to perform a matching move animation?

Comment: would love to know if you found anything for this, besides the answer below!

Comment: Sadly I filed a DTS ticket with Apple and they said it’s not currently possible to do what I want to do in SwiftUI. I ended up going with exposing an “all 52 cards” Array as a computed property, along with using anchor preferences and offsets to set the cards’ positions to allow for them to animate. (In other words, essentially the solution I’d hoped to avoid.)

Comment: Dang... thanks for letting me know, good to hear confirmation from Apple at least (suggest you answer this question with that answer yourself and maybe specify current Xcode version as hopefully it will change in the future!)

Comment: I’m wondering if it’s possible to achieve what you might do in UIKit and when a card needs to leave one view make it appear on top in a zstack, animate it moving to over its target view and then inserting it there... reckon it could get messy but I’ll probably give it a go!

Comment: What about using VStacks for the "stacks" (columns) and then anchorpreferencing to the bottom of it, moving the '9' card there, then without animation and trace for the user, removing the initial card from the view hierarchy and creating a new '9' card in its place, that is located inside the VStack? You don't have to expose all cards anymore, only the VStacks. And next time you move a card here, the VStack's bottom anchor will be lower. I reckon the number of columns is given, which helps this solution.

Comment: @iSpain17 I tried that approach (last year when I was working on this), and the problem is that by *removing* the card from the view hierarchy and *creating* a new one in the new location, SwiftUI couldn't match them up for the animation. That said, I think matchedGeometryEffect might solve this in iOS 14 - but I haven't had a need to go back and change my implementation, since what I ended up doing with the 52-card positioning worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Copied from a comment on the question)*

As of Xcode 11.3, iOS 13.3:

Sadly, I filed a DTS ticket with Apple and they said it’s not currently possible to do what I want to do in SwiftUI. I ended up going with exposing an “all 52 cards” Array as a computed property, along with using anchor preferences and offsets to set the cards’ positions to allow for them to animate. (In other words, essentially the solution I’d hoped to avoid.) Hopefully this is improved in iOS 14 / Xcode 12.

Answer (score 0):

I think for your case you need to count each card offset from some `@State var` (or more variables) for this behavior. I took your code and change the `BoardView`. When you tap the button every card offset change. It's only example that shows how card move to new position and may give you right direction:

```swift
struct BoardView: View {
    let board = Board()

    @State var cards = [
        Card.ten.ofDiamonds,
        Card.nine.ofSpades,
        Card.king.ofSpades,
        Card.queen.ofDiamonds,
        Card.jack.ofClubs,
        Card.ten.ofHearts
    ]

    @State var column1: Int = 2

    var body: some View {

        ZStack(alignment: .center) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)


            ZStack {
                ForEach(0..<self.cards.count, id: \.self) { cardIndex in
                    CardView(card: self.cards[cardIndex])
                        .offset(x: cardIndex < self.column1 ? 0 : 135,
                                y: 35*CGFloat(cardIndex >= self.column1 ? cardIndex - self.column1 : cardIndex))
                        .frame(width: 125, height: 187)
                }
            }.offset(x: -80, y: 0)


            Button(action: {
                withAnimation {
                    self.column1 -= 1

                }
            }) {
                Text("Move Card")
                    .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }
            .offset(x: 0, y: 300)
        }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

    }
}
```

so maybe the right solution is to move card from one array to another separately of changing it's offset.

Comment: Thanks - that's what I meant by "I can imagine some sort of alternate view hierarchy where there are just 52 CardViews with some sort of modifiers for the positions based on what column or location they're in, but that feels very hacky." It doesn't feel very Swift-y or SwiftUI-y to just have 52 cards laid out in one giant view without organization. Also, my actual use is like Solitaire and there are more card positions possible than just in the columns - the cards can be in other locations too - so even just handling the columns alone using offsets won't quite help.